# How to Redirect URLs from One Domain to Another Using .htaccess with Specific Folder Preservation?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-redirect

I'm trying to set up redirection rules in my .htaccess file to redirect URLs from one domain to another while preserving a specific folder structure within the URL. Specifically, I want to redirect requests from [www.example1.org/foldername/](http://www.example1.org/foldername/) to [www.example2.org/foldername/](http://www.example2.org/foldername/), ensuring that the /foldername/ folder is maintained in the redirected URL.

I've tried using the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example1\.org[NC]
RewriteRule ^example/(.*)$ https://www.example2.org/foldername/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, when I test this rule, the redirection works but it seems to strip off the /example/ folder, resulting in redirected URLs like https://www.example2.org/wp-content/themes/stratusx-child/template/upload/202011191605847805585.png instead of https://www.example2.org/foldername/wp-content/themes/stratusx-child/template/upload/202011191605847805585.png.

How can I modify the rewrite rule to ensure that the /foldername/ folder is preserved in the redirected URL?

Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is no way that the shown rule redirects you to an URL that does _not_ start with `https://www.example2.org/foldername/` - that part is hard-coded. If you end up on `https://www.example2.org/wp-content/...`- then there must be an additional redirect going on somewhere.

Comment: You seem to be switching between/mixing "example" and "foldername" to mean the same thing (even in the rule itself)?! " but it seems to strip off the /example/ folder" - Yes, that rule does strip the `/example/` folder, but I think your mean `/foldername/`?!